# Should I use cursor.delete() or objectStore.delete(id) for IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

If I want to delete all red cars in IndexedDB, which method is faster?

```
transaction.objectStore("cars").index("color").openCursor("red").onsuccess = e => {
  var row = e.target.result;
  if(row) {
    row.delete();
    row.continue();
  }
};
```

This method of deleting the cursor row is direct, but it requires using `openCursor` (instead of `openKeyCursor`) which unfortunately parses the whole object.

or

```
var cars = transaction.objectStore("cars");
cars.index("color").openKeyCursor("red").onsuccess = e => {
  var row = e.target.result;
  if(row) {
    cars.delete(row.primaryKey);
  }
};
```

This method doesn't require the cursor to parse the whole object, but `objectStore.delete()` might need to perform the search all over again.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.delete()` is essentially syntactic sugar for something like `cursor.source.delete()`. Both methods involve creating a new request on the current transaction. While the store method involves having to do a scan to find its value,  and the cursor method does not, both have roughly the same performance profile. Deleting the value at the cursor's current position using `cursor.delete()` is primarily a convenience, not an optimization.